# Why is the form action attribute empty on production server?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

After deploying a ASP.NET WebForms application to a production server some of the ajax calls has stopped working for me. After some debugging I found out that the following statement (in the internal client-method WebForm_DoCallback) was causing the problem:

```
xmlRequest.open("POST", action, true);
```

The problem seemed to be that the action-variable was empty so after checking the rendered html I found out that the form-tag rendered on the production server looks like:

```
<form method="post" action="" id="Form1">
```

However, on my developer machine I get the following:

```
<form method="post" action="default.aspx" id="Form1">
```

So, why would the action-attibute render on my dev.machine but not on the production server? This seems to be the case only for one specific web form, when I look on other pages the action-attribute renders correctly.

Any suggestions or ideas would be helpful!

Comment: [same issue with solution][1]
Look at the answer of EvilDr.

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9131966/asp-net-doesnt-populate-action-of-the-server-form-when-released

Answer (score 2):

I too have this issue. I installed dot net framework 4 on the production Windows 2003 R2 server, got the application running on IIS6, set it's framework to 4.0, put it in it's own app pool, then I got that. I've also noticed that it isn't loading up jscript one my login page, so perhaps it's a security issue?

Interesting though that when I go to the default page by selecting the site url
http://mysite
the action is not put in
But when I go there directly using an actual page (even though it's rendering exactly the same content) it puts the action in correctly.

Anyhow, my workaround was to set make the form runat=server (it may have been already) and then set the Action attribute on the server to the current Page.Path (could have been a different property, I forget) and that solved that particular problem.

However, I did come across a breaking changes document for the dot net 4 framework that talks about the blanking out of the action attribute:
http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes
see the section titled "Event Handlers Might Not Be Not Raised in a Default Document in IIS 7 or IIS 7.5 Integrated Mode"

Answer (score 0):

I'm probably way off, but since you asked for any suggestions...

I don't know much about ASP, but in PHP, `post` variables are passed from the `name` attribute of the inputs, not the `id` attribute of the form itself. For instance:

```
<form id="test" method="post" action="test.php">
    <fieldset>
        <input name="firstname" type="text" />
        <input name="lastname" type="text" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

And on the server_side, if you did:

```
 print_r($_POST);
```

You would get:

```
 Array (
    [firstname] => Joe
    [lastname] => Smith
 )
```

Other than that, the only things that come to mind are:

1. Make sure your form validates (the HTML itself),
2. Check to see if your DTD is set to Strict or Transitional,
3. Test to see if the issue is browser-side by testing on multiple variables,
4. Throw in a `type="hidden"` input with a pre-set value, to see if that gets back to the server.

I doubt any of this is going to solve the problem, but I hope at the very least one of my suggestions uncovers some aspect that leads to a solution.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET in .NET 3.5 Service Pack 1 [introduced some breaking changes regarding HTMLForm](http://forums.asp.net/t/1305800.aspx), so it may be worth checking that both servers have exactly the same framework version.

> "Previous versions of ASP.NET always
>   ignored the action attribute if it was
>   present in the declarative markup for
>   a  element.  Developers should
>   remove the action attribute from their
>   declarative markup to return to the
>   original behavior where ASP.NET
>   renders the postback Url."

Worth a shot.

Comment: it sounded like a good idea, but apparently the framework versions are exactly the same... I've solved the problem temporary by assigning the action-attribute in the client's onload-event, but i'll keep on looking at it..really strange behaviour...