# ASP.net doesn't populate action="" of the server form when released

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have an ASP.net webforms site, with a server form in the masterpage, as all pages require it.

When debugging the `action` parameter is populated at runtime along with the `id`, but when deployed on my server with IIS7 it doesn't appear... but still works. It's not causing the site issues, but its making my W3C HTML5 validation fail, as it needs to be populated.

Debug source:

```
<form method="post" action="index.aspx" id="aspnetForm">
```

Live source:

```
<form method="post" action="" id="aspnetForm">
```

Form declaration in masterpage:

```
<form runat="server">
.. some divs
</form>
```

I know the form tag doesnt have ID/action defined etc, because ASP configures the default at runtime and thats fine, although for some reason it messes up on my server. I've tried using the `action="<% Path etc %>"`, to get the path name but it doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong? Am I missing something, or is it just bad practise to use a form in a masterpage?

Thanks.

**Update**

Ok, to solve the issue pointed out in the answer I just set the Form.Action on the Masterpage Page_Load, finally got that W3C green light!

***Note**: I'm using Intelligencia Rewriter, but you can pull the URL using Request.Url*

```
public partial class myMasterPage : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form.Action = Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.RewriterHttpModule.RawUrl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Will changing it from `<form ...>` to `<asp:Form ...>` help?

Comment: Unknown server tag 'asp:Form'.

Comment: `Page.Form.Action = Request.Url.ToString();` worked for me, without Intelligencia, inside Page_Load.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

asp.net 4.0? If so, here's your answer: http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes#0.1__Toc256770154; It's not an easy read, and I'm not familiar myself, so you should probably read it and see how that affects your site.

Comment: looks like the culprite huh, will be in work tomorrow to check it out, great find though, thanks.

Comment: Definetly the issue, although struggling to populate that tag. tried in the web.config, machine.config in the IIS7 modules section, adding manually through command line. Nightmare!

Answer (score 4):

I just saw your post having had exactly the same experience.  In my opinion this is unintuitive *by-design* behaviour that will bring confusion to the majority of newer ASP.NET developers trying to grasp compliant HTML5.

Anyway after some tampering the problem can be fixed very easily using the following approach. **There is no need to tamper with the web.config - thankfully!**

In the Master page, add this snippet (or in the default page where this problem arises, if you're not using a master page)

```
Protected Sub Page_PreRender(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.PreRender
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        If Page.Form.Action = String.Empty Then
            Page.Form.Action = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Went with "Page.Form.Action = Request.RawUrl" to handle URLs with a query string. Thank you for pointing the way!

Comment: In case someone comes across this later, EvilDr's answer is ALMOST correct, but instead of using AbsolutePath you should use AbsoluteUri, or you will lose query strings if you use them in your pages. Just ran into this myself...

Comment: Yes you're quite correct.  The answer is updated. Developers can use this handy reference to check which property to use based on requirements (http://www.codepal.co.uk/show/Using_RequestUrl_to_find_specific_parts_of_the_web_pages_address)